# HTML form select not displaying as a dropdown correctly

Tags: html, select

I am practicing with creating forms and the select element.  See below for sample of my select code format.

```html
<select name="hobbies" multiple>
  <option value="reading">Reading</option>
  <option value="sports">Sports</option>
  <option value="movies">Movies</option>
  <option value="music">Music</option>
</select>
```

When I open the file with this code in Chrome or Edge it displays as a box with all four options showing.  I thought it should display as a small box with the top option showing and an arrow to click that would show the other options.  Is this code displaying correctly?  If yes what should I add to get the arrow dropdown option?

Comment: Remove the `multiple` attribute from select

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am new and did not know the multiple attribute did that. I thought multiple allowed the selection of multiple options by a user.

Comment: Yes, that it what it does. But as you can see then the options are not shown as a dropdown menu. Moreover, it's not really user friendly, because the user has to know that he'll need to use `ctrl` to select multiple options. If that's what you want, I would suggest using something different, like checkboxes

Comment: There are a plethora of third party replacements for the `select` element that provide a different user experience. A little searching will find many.